# HTML form inputs are NOT submitted

Tags: php, html

When I click submit I can't see $_GET['price'] in the url, the link after submission is

```
http://localhost/form.php/?submit=calculate!
```

I don't know why it is not like this

```
http://localhost/form.php/?submit=calculate!&price=3
```

even var_dump() returns NULL.

This is my code

```
<form action=""  method="get">

   <input type="number" name"price">
   <input type="submit" value="calculate!" name="submit">
</form>

<?php

var_dump($_GET['price']);

echo "<br/>";

$price = $_GET['price'];

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    if(!empty($price)){
    
      echo  "Good";

} else{

  echo 'something is wrong';

}

}

?>
```

It is so confusing, I used to do it right but there is something mysterious here.

Comment: its just url/percent encoded https://3v4l.org/ZiNdg

Comment: i really don't get what you said

Comment: remove `!` from `value="calculate!"` or use POST or learn how to handle chars encoded in the url

Comment: reason *price* is not being sent up is your missing a `=` in `name"price"`

Comment: lol omg i cant belive spending 3 hours on this thank you so much

Comment: you should just use an IDE that has code highlighting enabled. It should keep you away from issues like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser/Server handling invalid HTML best way they know how. Add an equals sign after name, so it recognizes the input with a named attr!

```
<input type="number" name="price">
```